# $filter angular returning object issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

i am working on angularjs .my LocationList having two properties ID and Name.Id are 1,11,13,14,15.

I wanted  name as per exact match ID 10.but problem is i am getting more than object.i mean it's not returning exact match ID value.why it's consider 1,11,13,14 15 as well.below is my code.please let me know how to get exact match value using filter.

```
Name = $filter('filter')($scope.LocationList, { ID: 10});


<div ng:app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="HelloCntl">
        <ul>
            <li > <span>{{itemxx[0].label}}</span>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('HelloCntl', [ '$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
        $scope.items = [
            { ID: 8, label: 'item 8' }, 
            { ID: 9, label: 'item 9' }, 
            { ID: 13, label: 'item 13' } ,
            { ID: 10, label: 'item 10'}, 
            { ID: 1, label: 'item 1'}, 
            { ID: 11, label: 'item 11' }, 
            { ID: 12, label: 'item 12' } 
        ];

    $scope.itemxx = $filter('filter')($scope.items, { ID: 1 });
    //console.log(item10);
}]);
```

her items ID is not ordered.so when i am trying to get value of ID 1 then its returing value of Id 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).filter('ID', function(){
    return function(items, value){
        return items.filter(function(item) { return item.ID === value });
    };
});
```

Here's a full jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jochenvanwylick/0suogLpk/

Usage:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | ID: 10">
    <span>{{item.label}}</span>
</li>
```

**EDIT**

You do not need to write a special filter as it turns out, you can just use out-of-the-box filtering:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {ID:10}">
    <span>{{item.label}}</span>
</li>
```

**EDIT 2**

I misunderstood - you're trying to do this in the controller, AND there's a small catch in the AngularJS filter. By default it will treat the object property value as a string and then do a 'contains' like filter operation on it.

If you want exact matching, you'll have to utilize the 3rd argument of the filter function, the `comparator` and supply an exactmatch comparator:

```
$filter('filter')($scope.items, { ID: 1 }, function(a,b) { return a === b; });
```

This will effectively do a `1 === 1` comparison and thus will return true for this case and false in any other. ( http://jsfiddle.net/jochenvanwylick/0suogLpk/7/ )

Comment: thanks..but i don't want to go this approach.i wanted to get name in controller using $filter('filter').pls let me know using $filter('filter')

Comment: So are you saying you're not doing this in the view - but in the controller? Then you can just use JavaScript: `var nameOfItemWithIdTen = $scope.LocationList.filter(function(item) { return item.ID === 10 })[0].name;`

Comment: as per your solution we need to add more filter in module if  we have different filter like ID, CityId,CountryId.Correct?woutout adding filter in module we have different approach..pls suggest

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. You mean this then `var item10 = $filter('filter')($scope.items, { ID: 10 });` ? Full Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jochenvanwylick/0suogLpk/2/

Comment: yes,i want exact match here.$scope.items = [
            { ID: 8, label: 'item 8' }, 
            { ID: 9, label: 'item 9' }, 
            { ID: 10, label: 'item 10'}, 
            { ID: 1, label: 'item 1'}, 
            { ID: 11, label: 'item 11' }, 
            { ID: 12, label: 'item 12' } 
        ];
                    
    $scope.itemxx = $filter('filter')($scope.items, { ID: 1 });
html code <ul>
            <li > <span>{{itemxx[0].label}}</span>

            </li>

if i use above code then getting wrong value.

Comment: pls chek edited comments.my Id is not ordered but when i am using id 1 then its returing item 10 istead of item 1'.this is my problem and need to resolve this issue

Comment: you understand my problem?

Comment: @user3310138 Post a full fiddle/plncker example. You are leaving something important out.

Comment: @user3310138 - I think I've finally got it, I updated my answer

Comment: i didnt get you.still i am getting same issue if i use your above code.could you pls provide fidler?

Comment: It's there: http://jsfiddle.net/jochenvanwylick/0suogLpk/7/ . But @PerHornshøj-Schierbeck has an even more elegant solution: just use `true` for the 3rd parameter to enable strict equality comparison. That would look someting like http://jsfiddle.net/jochenvanwylick/0suogLpk/8/

Answer (score 0):

Your example will return an array of objects matching `ID: 1`. If you have multiple items in that list, your will get multiple results.

If you know - or don't care - that there will always be excatly one match, you can get your result like this:

```
var Name = $filter('filter')($scope.LocationList, { ID: 1 }, true)[0];
```

Notice the indexer `[0]` on the result of `$filter` to get the first element in the return list. Also notice the `true` parameter stating that the match has to be excat (not matching 11, 12, 13, etc)

http://plnkr.co/edit/gY7yeflfpURFfWsfV0Ro?p=preview

If you still don't get the expected result, use console.log($scope.LocationList) and expect the result in the chrome(pref. for me) console window. Alternativly you can write the content like this in the HTML

```
{{ LocationList | json }}
```

To inspect the object.